# How to send curl request in react/javascript using fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, curl, fetch, fetch-api

I want to make a request..This is the curl request

```
curl --location --request POST '2.2.2.22:343/sudun/cars' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer sdswmaiqwasae*********' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "user": "sdsffwefwefwssdsds",
    "numberofunits": 4,
    "price": 0
}'
```

This is the way I am doing.

```
const url = "2.2.2.22:343/sudun/cars";

const options = {
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer sdswmaiqwasae*********",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
};

fetch(url, options)
  .then( res => res.json() )
  .then( data => console.log(data) );
```

It is not working...I know i have not added --data-raw part ...I don't know how to do that..

Comment: You forgot to include the JSON body.

Comment: The URL is missing the scheme

Comment: [it is not working](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) isn't a useful description of the problem

Comment: @Quentin   I cannot share the error...Where to add ---data--raw ?

Comment: Also, you will need to make sure the endpoint has CORS configured in a way that you can send a request to it from the browser.

Comment: @AKX can you help me with the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like this if you are using fetch.

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer sdswmaiqwasae*********");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  "user": "sdsffwefwefwssdsds",
  "numberofunits": 4,
  "price": 0
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("2.2.2.22:343/sudun/cars", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```